# Как правильно записать значение в value input'а?

Tags: javascript, jquery, form, input

Значит записываю я значение (value) инпату с помощью jQuery и визуально оно записывается (в поле появляется необходимое значение), только вот форма говорит, что оно пустое. Из за чего и не отправляется.

```js
var arr = [{
    value: 6,
    list: [{
        value: 0,
        text: 'A3'
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        text: 'A4'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: 'A5'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    value: 7,
    list: [{
        value: 0,
        text: 'M3'
      },
      {
        value: 1,
        text: 'M6'
      },
      {
        value: 2,
        text: 'X5'
      },
      {
        value: 3,
        text: 'X6'
      }
    ]
  },
];

$("#category").change(function() {
  selval = $(this).val();
  forval = arr[selval - 6].list;
  $("#selectmodel").empty();
  $.each(forval, function(i, val) {
    $("#selectmodel").append("<option value='" + val.text + "'>" + val.text + "</option>");
  })
});
$("#selectmodel").change(function() {
  text = $(this).val();
  $("#xf_model").val(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="category">
  <option value="6">значение 6</option>
  <option value="7">значение 7</option>
</select>
<select id="selectmodel">
</select>
<input type="text" name="xfield[model]" id="xf_model" value="" rel="essential" data-rel="links" />
```

Comment: А как именно форма "говорит, что оно пустое"? Поясните, как вы это проверяете. Проверка идет на сервере? Если да, приложите еще и код проверки.

Comment: Дело не в проверке, хоть на сервере, хоть в клиенте говорит, что поле пустое (без проверки никуда). А если нажать Ctrl+Shift+I то value у input пустое.

Comment: так оно там и не должно меняться. Там HTML отображается. Вы сначала попробуйте на сервере получить данные. А потом уже говорите, что не передается. У меня все прекрасно работает: http://main.xfiddle.com/19a5ec5b/1.php

Comment: Если в ручную вписываю в поле значение, форма отправляет без проблем.
Если же скриптом записываю, форма ругает на не заполненное поле

Comment: я как раз об этом и спрашиваю. Как именно форма ругается? Как вы проверяете что значение заполнено? Если с помощью JS, приведите код проверки. Вы смотрели пример по ссылке? Там же ни чего не ругается и данные отправляются.